# Audio steganography using phase encoding technique

Tags: fft, audio, phase, steganography

I referred the below papers to understand the working of Phase Encoding,but the explanation is not proper.Just a few steps have been given in brief.

[ijcsi.org](http://ijcsi.org/papers/IJCSI-9-1-2-402-406.pdf)

[www.ijarcce.com](http://www.ijarcce.com/upload/june/11_LSB%20Modification%20and%20Phase%20Encoding%20Technique%20of%20Audio%20Steganography%20Revisited.pdf)

Can someone please explain the concept of how Audio Steganography using Phase Encoding works?

Comment: http://www.snotmonkey.com/work/school/405/methods.html#phase and http://herkules.oulu.fi/isbn9514273842/isbn9514273842.pdf#page=43 have some explanations

Answer (score 2):

Here is the algorithm:

1. Divide an input signal $S$ into $n$ consecutive blocks $S_i$ ($i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$) of length $l$ each
2. Compute magnitude $A_i$ and phase $\phi_i$ of each block using [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) where `A(i)=abs(fft(S{i}))` and `Phi(i)=angle(fft(S{i}))` in [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/angle.html).

   For example, here are the first 3 elements of $\phi$:
   [image: Input phases of the first 3 segments]
   (Recall that FFT of real signal has odd symmetry which is clearly visible on plots)
3. Compute phase differences $\Delta\phi_i=\phi_i-\phi_{i-1}$ for $i\in\{2,\ldots,n\}$
4. To encode your binary data $d$ of length $m:m<l$ assign
   $$\phi_{data}[i]=
   \begin{cases}
   \pi/2,& d_i=0\\
   -\pi/2,& d_i=1
   \end{cases}$$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$.
5. Replace following elements of first phase sequence, $ {\phi_1} $,  with ${\phi _{data}}[i]$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ as:
   $${\phi '_1}[ {L/2 - m + i}] = {\phi _{data}}[i]\,$$
   To maintain odd symmetry property of DFT, repeat same progress as:
   $${\phi '_1}[{L/2 + 1 + i}] =  - {\phi _{data}}[{m + 1 - i}]$$
6. To maintain phase differences sequentially reassign $\phi '_i=\phi_{i-1}+\Delta\phi_i$ for $i\in\{2,\ldots,n\}$
   Here are the first 3 elements of $\phi '$ after this step:
   [image]
   (Note how encoded $d$ has affected next blocks)
7. Reconstruct the signal using inverse FFT applied to each block $A_i exp(j \phi '_i)$ (where $j$ is imaginary unit) and joining all blocks together.

Explanations to many details like the length of blocks and why particular steps are taken are given in the documents you and [endolith linked to](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/audio-steganography-using-phase-encoding-technique/30464?noredirect=1#comment29453_14804).

A minimal IPython Notebook version: github.com/danylo-dubinin/secret_in_wav.

Comment: What an awesome answer!

Comment: Would love to see a toy implementation of this!

Comment: @PetrusTheron, cool! Thanks for being interested :) I have a minimal IPython Notebook version here https://github.com/danylo-dubinin/secret_in_wav. It's without the graphs which i showed in this answer because they are from Mathematica version of this program which I didn't publish back then. I can publish it later too though if you want :) Should be still somewhere on the old laptop.

Comment: Hi @danoak, thanks! I'm a Clojure guy, so Mathematica version would be much appreciated :)